# How can I replace a string in a file(s)?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

Replacing strings in files based on certain search criteria is a very common task. How can I

- replace string `foo` with `bar` in all files in the current directory?
- do the same recursively for sub directories?
- replace only if the file name matches another string?
- replace only if the string is found in a certain context?
- replace if the string is on a certain line number?
- replace multiple strings with the same replacement
- replace multiple strings with different replacements

Comment: This is intended to be a canonical Q&A on this subject (see this [meta discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/2708/22222)), please feel free to edit my answer below or add your own.

Comment: Great `grep -rl` (then piped to `sed`) answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472476/grep-global-find-replace/472482#472482

Answer (score 1281, accepted):

### 1. Replacing all occurrences of one string with another in all files in the current directory:

These are for cases where you  *know* that the directory contains only regular files and that you want to process all non-hidden files. If that is not the case, use the approaches in 2.

All `sed` solutions in this answer assume GNU `sed`. If using FreeBSD or macOS, replace `-i` with `-i ''`. Also note that the use of the `-i` switch with any version of `sed` has certain filesystem [security implications](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2013-09/msg00000.html) and is inadvisable in any script which you plan to distribute in any way.

- Non recursive, files in this directory only:

  ```
   sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *
   perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g' ./*
  ```

(the [`perl` one will fail for file names ending in `|` or space)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013/22565)).

- Recursive, regular files (**including hidden ones**) in this and all subdirectories

  ```
   find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
  ```

  If you are using zsh:

  ```
   sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*(D.)
  ```

  (may fail if the list is too big, see `zargs` to work around).

  Bash can't check directly for regular files, a loop is needed (braces avoid setting the options globally):

  ```
   ( shopt -s globstar dotglob;
       for file in **; do
           if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
               sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' "$file"
           fi
       done
   )
  ```

  The files are selected when they are actual files (-f) and they are writable (-w).

### 2. Replace only if the file name matches another string / has a specific extension / is of a certain type etc:

- Non-recursive, files in this directory only:

  ```
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *baz*    ## all files whose name contains baz
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' *.baz    ## files ending in .baz
  ```
- Recursive, regular files in this and all subdirectories

  ```
  find . -type f -name "*baz*" -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
  ```

  If you are using bash (braces avoid setting the options globally):

  ```
  ( shopt -s globstar dotglob
      sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **baz*
      sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **.baz
  )
  ```

  If you are using zsh:

  ```
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*baz*(D.)
  sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*.baz(D.)
  ```

The `--` serves to tell `sed` that no more flags will be given in the command line. This is useful to protect against file names starting with `-`.

- If a file is of a certain type, for example, executable (see `man find` for more options):

  ```
  find . -type f -executable -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
  ```

`zsh`:

```
    sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*(D*)
```

### 3. Replace only if the string is found in a certain context

- Replace `foo` with `bar` only if there is a `baz` later on the same line:

  ```
   sed -i 's/foo\(.*baz\)/bar\1/' file
  ```

In `sed`, using `\( \)` saves whatever is in the parentheses and you can then access it with `\1`.  There are many variations of this theme, to learn more about such regular expressions, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

- Replace `foo` with `bar` only if `foo` is found on the 3d column (field) of the input file (assuming whitespace-separated fields):

  ```
   gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/foo/,"baz",$3); print}' file
  ```

(needs `gawk` 4.1.0 or newer).

- For a different field just use `$N` where `N` is the number of the field of interest. For a different field separator (`:` in this example) use:

  ```
   gawk -i inplace -F':' '{gsub(/foo/,"baz",$3);print}' file
  ```

Another solution using `perl`:

```
    perl -i -ane '$F[2]=~s/foo/baz/g; $" = " "; print "@F\n"' foo
```

NOTE: both the `awk` and `perl` solutions will affect spacing in the file (remove the leading and trailing blanks, and convert sequences of blanks to one space character in those lines that match). For a different field, use `$F[N-1]` where `N` is the field number you want and for a different field separator use (the `$"=":"` sets the output field separator to `:`):

```
    perl -i -F':' -ane '$F[2]=~s/foo/baz/g; $"=":";print "@F"' foo
```

- Replace `foo` with `bar` only on the 4th line:

  ```
   sed -i '4s/foo/bar/g' file
   gawk -i inplace 'NR==4{gsub(/foo/,"baz")};1' file
   perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g if $.==4' file
  ```

### 4. Multiple replace operations: replace with different strings

- You can combine `sed` commands:

  ```
   sed -i 's/foo/bar/g; s/baz/zab/g; s/Alice/Joan/g' file
  ```

Be aware that order matters (`sed 's/foo/bar/g; s/bar/baz/g'` will substitute `foo` with `baz`).

- or Perl commands

  ```
   perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g; s/baz/zab/g; s/Alice/Joan/g' file
  ```
- If you have a large number of patterns, it is easier to save your patterns and their replacements in a `sed` script file:

  ```
   #! /usr/bin/sed -f
   s/foo/bar/g
   s/baz/zab/g
  ```
- Or, if you have too many pattern pairs for the above to be feasible, you can read pattern pairs from a file (two space separated patterns, $pattern and $replacement, per line):

  ```
   while read -r pattern replacement; do   
       sed -i "s/$pattern/$replacement/" file
   done < patterns.txt
  ```
- That will be quite slow for long lists of patterns and large data files so you might want to read the patterns and create a `sed` script from them instead. The following assumes a *<<!>space<!>>* delimiter separates a list of *MATCH<<!>space<!>>REPLACE* pairs occurring one-per-line in the file *`patterns.txt`* :

  ```
   sed 's| *\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\).*|s/\1/\2/g|' <patterns.txt |
   sed -f- ./editfile >outfile
  ```

The above format is largely arbitrary and, for example, doesn't allow for a *<<!>space<!>>* in either of *MATCH* or *REPLACE*. The method is very general though: basically, if you can create an output stream which looks like a `sed` script, then you can source that stream as a `sed` script by specifying `sed`'s script file as `-`stdin.

- You can combine and concatenate multiple scripts in similar fashion:

  ```
   SOME_PIPELINE |
   sed -e'#some expression script'  \
       -f./script_file -f-          \
       -e'#more inline expressions' \
   ./actual_edit_file >./outfile
  ```

A POSIX `sed` will concatenate all scripts into one in the order they appear on the command-line. None of these need end in a `\n`ewline.

- `grep` can work the same way:

  ```
   sed -e'#generate a pattern list' <in |
   grep -f- ./grepped_file
  ```
- When working with fixed-strings as patterns, it is good practice to escape regular expression *metacharacters*. You can do this rather easily:

  ```
   sed 's/[]$&^*\./[]/\\&/g
        s| *\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\).*|s/\1/\2/g|
   ' <patterns.txt |
   sed -f- ./editfile >outfile
  ```

### 5. Multiple replace operations: replace multiple patterns with the same string

- Replace any of `foo`, `bar` or `baz` with `foobar`

  ```
   sed -Ei 's/foo|bar|baz/foobar/g' file
  ```
- or

  ```
   perl -i -pe 's/foo|bar|baz/foobar/g' file
  ```

### 6. Replace File paths in multiple files

- Another use case of using different delimiter:

  ```
   sed -i 's|path/to/foo|path/to/bar|g' *
  ```
- or

  ```
   perl -i -pe 's|path/to/foo|path/to/bar|g' ./*
  ```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the edit, it did indeed fix several things. However, please don't remove information that is relevant to bash. Not everyone uses `zsh`. By all means add `zsh` info but there is no reason to remove the bash stuff. Also, I know that using the shell for text processing is not ideal but there are cases where it is needed. I edited in a better version of my original script that will create a `sed` script instead of actually using the shell loop to parse. This can be useful if you have several hundred pairs of patterns for example.

Comment: @terdon, your bash one is incorrect. bash before 4.3 will follow symlinks when descending. Also bash has no equivalent for the `(.)` globbing qualifier so can't be used here. (you're missing some -- as well). The for loop is incorrect (missing -r) and means making several passes in the files and adds no benefit over a sed script.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't see why following symlinks is a problem here. If the links are in the directory in most cases I would want to follow them. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean about the `(.)` which is, I guess, some `zsh` magic I am unfamiliar with. I fixed the shell loop (and added a few `--` though not in all examples), its point is in dealing with hundreds of patterns and will only read the pattern file once. It produces a sed script.

Comment: @terdon What does `--` after  `sed -i` and before the  substitute command indicate?

Comment: @Geek that's a POSIX thing. It signifies the end of options and lets you pass arguments starting with `-`.  Using it ensures that the commands will work on files with names like `-foo`. Without it, the `-f` would be parsed as an option.

Comment: @terdon One more follow-up question. In the last example `sed -Ei 's/foo|bar|baz/foobar/g' file` I think that the E stands for extended regular expression.  Is this a Posix feature?

Comment: @Geek no, it's [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). It is also not GNU. As far as I can tell [it's a BSD thing](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man1/sed.1.html) (so, by extension, OSX as well). That was added by Stéphane Chazelas (see edit 10), not me, but I'm sure he's right. He tends to be. Presumably, the BSD sed won't interpret the `|` correctly without the `-E`.

Comment: For me, the #! /usr/bin/sed -i  doesn't work. You need to give sed the -f argument to make it treat the file as scriptfile. Unfortunately you can't give it -i as well, so that script can just work as a filter.

Comment: @hstoerr yes, same here. Sorry about that. I don't know who made that particular edit. Fixed now.

Comment: Be very careful executing some of the recursive commands in git repositories.  For example, the solutions provided in section 1 of this answer will actually modify internal git files in a `.git` directory, and actually mess up your checkout.  Better to operate within/on specific directories by name.

Comment: In the first case with recursive directory search, how can I also include executables?

Comment: @Mellkor that already does include executables. Executable files, be they binary or text, are still just files.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention **repren**, which is another approach to this. It is my own Python tool and so must be installed with pip, but covers most of these scenarios and several others (like dry runs, stats, and multiple simultaneous replacements) that you can't replicate with sed and perl: https://github.com/jlevy/repren

Comment: @jlevy sounds like that might make a good answer. Why not post one with a few examples?

Comment: Apparently I can't (the question is protected). In any case, three short examples are here (search for repren): https://github.com/jlevy/the-art-of-command-line#processing-files-and-data

Comment: The mentioned security issue should be considered as an operating system bug. Otherwise, there is no need for permissions on file level [Any file in an rw directory is writable by renaming the old file]

Comment: Beware that #1 bullet 2 may damage your git index if you have one.

Comment: Recursive doesn't work for me. It's not the number of files; I moved down several directories and it still doesn't change the text.

Comment: @felwithe please post a new question, explaining exactly what you are trying to do. These commands are pretty standard, so if they don't work, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I suggest adding a section to the recursive option here to exclude `.hg`, `.git`, and `.svn` directories. That's the sort of thing one only thinks about when it's too late.

Comment: @Pistos it is not only about .git files but affects all files in the directory. So, it would be much safer if a file ending "*.txt" or similar was added.

Answer (score 113):

A good [r](http://rpl.sourceforge.net/)e[pl](http://rpl.sourceforge.net/)acement Linux tool is **[rpl](http://rpl.sourceforge.net/)**, that was originally written for the Debian project, so it is available with `apt-get install rpl` in any Debian derived distro, and may be for others, but otherwise you can download the `tar.gz` file from [SourceForge](http://rpl.sourceforge.net/).

Simplest example of use:

```
 $ rpl old_string new_string test.txt
```

Note that if the string contains spaces it should be enclosed in quotation marks. By default `rpl` takes care of **capital letters** but not of **complete words**, but you can change these defaults with options `-i` (ignore case) and `-w` (whole words). You can also specify **multiple files**:

```
 $ rpl -i -w "old string" "new string" test.txt test2.txt
```

Or even specify the **extensions** (`-x`) to search or even search **recursively** (`-R`) in the directory:

```
 $ rpl -x .html -x .txt -R old_string new_string test*
```

You can also search/replace in **interactive mode** with `-p` (prompt) option:

The output shows the numbers of files/string replaced and the type of search (case in/sensitive, whole/partial words), but it can be silent with the `-q` (**quiet mode**) option, or even more verbose, listing line numbers that contain matches of each file and directory with `-v` (**verbose mode**) option.

Other options that are worth remembering are `-e` (honor **e**scapes) that allow `regular expressions`, so you can search also tabs (`\t`), new lines (`\n`),etc. You can use `-f` to **force permissions** (of course, only when the user has write permissions) and `-d` to preserve the modification times`).

Finally, if you are unsure what exactly will happen, use the `-s` (**simulate mode**).

Comment: So much better at the feedback and simplicity than sed.  I just wish it allowed acting on file names, and then it'd be perfect as-is.

Comment: i like the -s (simulate mode) :-)

Comment: sooo much better than `sed`. golly

Comment: thanks so much for this. `sed` is fine for simple replacements, but terrible for more complicated and longer strings

Comment: For macOS, `rpl` is available from MacPorts.

Comment: I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 293: ordinal not in range(128)`. The command is `rpl -x .php -R -p -v ".frames['tudo']" "" *`. Any ideas?

Comment: Check with single files, probably have some with the wrong encoding. Use `uconv` if needed.

Comment: rpl seems nice, but for various random files it gives me `decoding error (character maps to <undefined>)`. I got lucky using verbose mode or I might not have noticed until much later... Perhaps it's because some of my README.md files have emojis in them? Either way, back to good ol find + sed.

Comment: This is awesome, many thanks

Answer (score 28):

[How to do a search and replace over multiple files](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_search_and_replace_multiple_files.php) suggests:

> You could also use find and sed, but I find that this little line of
>   perl works nicely.
>
> ```
> perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' *.php
> ```
>
> - -e means execute the following line of code.
> - -i means edit in-place
> - -w write warnings
> - -p loop over the input file, printing each line after the script is applied to it.

My best results come from using perl and grep (to ensure that file have the search expression )

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' $( grep -rl 'search' )
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

> replace string ALF with BRA in all files in the current directory?

```
for CHA in *
do
  ex -sc '%s/ALF/BRA/g' -cx "$CHA"
done
```

---

> do the same recursively for sub directories?

```
find -type f -exec ex -sc '%s/ALF/BRA/g' -cx {} ';'
```

---

> replace only if the file name matches another string?

```
for CHA in *.txt
do
  ex -sc '%s/ALF/BRA/g' -cx "$CHA"
done
```

---

> replace only if the string is found in a certain context?

```
ex -sc 'g/DEL/s/ALF/BRA/g' -cx file
```

---

> replace if the string is on a certain line number?

```
ex -sc '2s/ALF/BRA/g' -cx file
```

---

> replace multiple strings with the same replacement

```
ex -sc '%s/\vALF|ECH/BRA/g' -cx file
```

---

> replace multiple strings with different replacements

```
ex -sc '%s/ALF/BRA/g|%s/FOX/GOL/g' -cx file
```

Answer (score 19):

I used this:

```
grep -r "old_string" -l | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g'
```

1. List all files that contain `old_string`.
2. Replace newline in result with spaces (so that the list of files can be fed to `sed`.
3. Run `sed` on those files to replace old string with new.

**Update:** The above result will fail on filenames that contain whitespaces. Instead, use:

`grep --null -lr "old_string" | xargs --null sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g'`

Comment: Note that this will fail if any of your file names contain spaces, tabs or newlines. Use `grep --null -lr "old_string"   | xargs --null sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g'` will make it deal with arbitrary file names.

Comment: thanks guys. added update and left the old code cause it's an interesting caveat that could be useful to someone unaware of this behavior.

Answer (score 9):

From a user's perspective, a nice & simple Unix tool that does the job perfectly is [`qsubst`](http://freecode.com/projects/qsubst). For example,

```
% qsubst foo bar *.c *.h
```

will replace `foo` with `bar` in all my C files. A nice feature is that `qsubst` will do a *query-replace*, i.e., it will show me each occurrence of `foo` and ask whether I want to replace it or not. [You can replace unconditionally (no asking) with `-go` option, and there are other options, e.g., `-w` if you only want to replace `foo` when it is a whole word.]

How to get it: `qsubst` was invented by der Mouse (from McGill) and posted to *comp.unix.sources 11(7)* in Aug. 1987. Updated versions exist. For example, the NetBSD version `qsubst.c,v 1.8 2004/11/01` compiles and runs perfectly on my mac.

Comment: Searched similar solution for Linux and found `wrg` script wrapper for ripgrep by lydell: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-309213936

Answer (score 7):

[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (command name `rg`) is a `grep` tool, but supports search and replace as well.

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt
dark blue and light blue
light orange
blue sky
$ # by default, line number is displayed if output destination is stdout
$ # by default, only lines that matched the given pattern is displayed
$ # 'blue' is search pattern and -r 'red' is replacement string
$ rg 'blue' -r 'red' ip.txt
1:dark red and light red
3:red sky

$ # --passthru option is useful to print all lines, whether or not it matched
$ # -N will disable line number prefix
$ # this command is similar to: sed 's/blue/red/g' ip.txt
$ rg --passthru -N 'blue' -r 'red' ip.txt
dark red and light red
light orange
red sky
```

`rg` doesn't support in-place option, so you'll have to do it yourself

```bsh
$ # -N isn't needed here as output destination is a file
$ rg --passthru 'blue' -r 'red' ip.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt ip.txt
$ cat ip.txt
dark red and light red
light orange
red sky
```

See [Rust regex documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.9/regex/index.html) for regular expression syntax and features. The `-P` switch will enable [PCRE2](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/index.html) flavor. `rg` supports Unicode by default.

```bsh
$ # non-greedy quantifier is supported
$ echo 'food land bark sand band cue combat' | rg 'foo.*?ba' -r 'X'
Xrk sand band cue combat

$ # unicode support
$ echo 'fox:αλεπού,eagle:αετός' | rg '\p{L}+' -r '($0)'
(fox):(αλεπού),(eagle):(αετός)

$ # set operator example, remove all punctuation characters except . ! and ?
$ para='"Hi", there! How *are* you? All fine here.'
$ echo "$para" | rg '[[:punct:]--[.!?]]+' -r ''
Hi there! How are you? All fine here.

$ # use -P if you need even more advanced features
$ echo 'car bat cod map' | rg -P '(bat|map)(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+' -r '[$0]'
[car] bat [cod] map
```

Like `grep`, the `-F` option will allow fixed strings to be matched, a handy option which I feel `sed` should implement too.

```bsh
$ printf '2.3/[4]*6\nfoo\n5.3-[4]*9\n' | rg --passthru -F '[4]*' -r '2'
2.3/26
foo
5.3-29
```

Another handy option is `-U` which enables multiline matching

```bsh
$ # (?s) flag will allow . to match newline characters as well
$ printf '42\nHi there\nHave a Nice Day' | rg --passthru -U '(?s)the.*ice' -r ''
42
Hi  Day
```

`rg` can handle dos-style files too

```bsh
$ # same as: sed -E 's/\w+(\r?)$/123\1/'
$ printf 'hi there\r\ngood day\r\n' | rg --passthru --crlf '\w+$' -r '123'
hi 123
good 123
```

Another advantage of `rg` is that it is likely to be faster than `sed`

```bsh
$ # for small files, initial processing time of rg is a large component
$ time echo 'aba' | sed 's/a/b/g' > f1
real    0m0.002s
$ time echo 'aba' | rg --passthru 'a' -r 'b' > f2
real    0m0.007s

$ # for larger files, rg is likely to be faster
$ # 6.2M sample ASCII file
$ wget https://norvig.com/big.txt
$ time LC_ALL=C sed 's/\bcat\b/dog/g' big.txt > f1
real    0m0.060s
$ time rg --passthru '\bcat\b' -r 'dog' big.txt > f2
real    0m0.048s
$ diff -s f1 f2
Files f1 and f2 are identical

$ time LC_ALL=C sed -E 's/\b(\w+)(\s+\1)+\b/\1/g' big.txt > f1
real    0m0.725s
$ time rg --no-unicode --passthru -wP '(\w+)(\s+\1)+' -r '$1' big.txt > f2
real    0m0.093s
$ diff -s f1 f2
Files f1 and f2 are identical
```

Answer (score 6):

I needed something that would provide a dry-run option and would work recursively with a glob, and after trying to do it with `awk` and `sed` I gave up and instead did it in python.

The [script](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/04f78bde56f5e914f1c9acddf51bc013) searches recursively all files matching a glob pattern (e.g. `--glob="*.html"`) for a regex and replaces with the replacement regex:

```bash
find_replace.py [--dir=my_folder] \
    --search-regex=<search_regex> \
    --replace-regex=<replace_regex> \
    --glob=[glob_pattern] \
    --dry-run
```

<sup>Every long option such as `--search-regex` has a corresponding short option, i.e. `-s`. Run with `-h` to see all options.</sup>

For example, this will flip all dates from `2017-12-31` to `31-12-2017`:

```bash
python replace.py --glob=myfile.txt \
    --search-regex="(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})" \
    --replace-regex="\3-\2-\1" \
    --dry-run --verbose
```

```python
import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import shutil
import re

import argparse

def find_replace(cfg):
    search_pattern = re.compile(cfg.search_regex)

    if cfg.dry_run:
        print('THIS IS A DRY RUN -- NO FILES WILL BE CHANGED!')

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(cfg.dir)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, cfg.glob):

            if cfg.print_parent_folder:
                pardir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(path, '..'))
                pardir = os.path.split(pardir)[-1]
                print('[%s]' % pardir)
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)

            # backup original file
            if cfg.create_backup:
                backup_path = filepath + '.bak'

                while os.path.exists(backup_path):
                    backup_path += '.bak'
                print('DBG: creating backup', backup_path)
                shutil.copyfile(filepath, backup_path)

            with open(filepath) as f:
                old_text = f.read()

            all_matches = search_pattern.findall(old_text)

            if all_matches:

                print('Found {} matches in file {}'.format(len(all_matches), filename))

                new_text = search_pattern.sub(cfg.replace_regex, old_text)

                if not cfg.dry_run:
                    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                        print('DBG: replacing in file', filepath)
                        f.write(new_text)
                else:
                    for idx, matches in enumerate(all_matches):
                        print("Match #{}: {}".format(idx, matches))

                    print("NEW TEXT:\n{}".format(new_text))

            elif cfg.verbose:
                print('File {} does not contain search regex "{}"'.format(filename, cfg.search_regex))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''DESCRIPTION:
    Find and replace recursively from the given folder using regular expressions''',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     epilog='''USAGE:
    {0} -d [my_folder] -s <search_regex> -r <replace_regex> -g [glob_pattern]

    '''.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))

    parser.add_argument('--dir', '-d',
                        help='folder to search in; by default current folder',
                        default='.')

    parser.add_argument('--search-regex', '-s',
                        help='search regex',
                        required=True)

    parser.add_argument('--replace-regex', '-r',
                        help='replacement regex',
                        required=True)

    parser.add_argument('--glob', '-g',
                        help='glob pattern, i.e. *.html',
                        default="*.*")

    parser.add_argument('--dry-run', '-dr',
                        action='store_true',
                        help="don't replace anything just show what is going to be done",
                        default=False)

    parser.add_argument('--create-backup', '-b',
                        action='store_true',
                        help='Create backup files',
                        default=False)

    parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v',
                        action='store_true',
                        help="Show files which don't match the search regex",
                        default=False)

    parser.add_argument('--print-parent-folder', '-p',
                        action='store_true',
                        help="Show the parent info for debug",
                        default=False)

    config = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    find_replace(config)
```

> <sup>[`Here`](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/04f78bde56f5e914f1c9acddf51bc013) is an updated version of the script which highlights the search terms and replacements with different colors.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand why you would make something this complex. For recursion, use either bash's (or your shell's equivalent) `globstar` option and `**` globs or `find`. For a dry run, just use `sed`. Unless you use the `-i` option, it won't make any changes. For a backup use `sed -i.bak` (or `perl -i .bak`); for files that don't match, use `grep PATTERN file || echo file`. And why in the world would you have python expand the glob instead of letting the shell do it? Why `script.py --glob=foo*` instead of just `script.py foo*`?

Comment: My _why's_ are very simple: (1) above all, ease of debugging; (2) using only a single well documented tool with a supportive community (3) not knowing `sed` and `awk` well and being unwilling to invest extra time on mastering them, (4) readability, (5) this solution will also work on non-posix systems (not that I need that but somebody else might).

Answer (score 2):

**Update July 2022: I have a *really robust* wrapper tool, `rgr`, which stands for "RipGrep Replace" and which wraps the incredibly fast [RipGrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) tool (`rg`), which you should use instead. See [my other answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684926/114401). My wrapper supports *all* `rg` options, while adding `-R` for actual, on-disk text replacements.**

---

Here I use `grep` to tell if it *is going to* change a file (so I can count the number of lines changed, and replacements made, to output at the end), then I use `sed` to actually change the file. Notice the single line of `sed` usage at the *very end* of the Bash function below:

### `replace_str` Bash function

*Update: the below code has been upgraded and is now part of my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) project as "[find_and_replace.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/find_and_replace.sh)" here. <-- I recommend you use this tool now instead.*

**Usage**:

```
gs_replace_str "regex_search_pattern" "replacement_string" "file_path"
```

**Bash Function:**

```
# Usage: `gs_replace_str "regex_search_pattern" "replacement_string" "file_path"`
gs_replace_str() {
    REGEX_SEARCH="$1"
    REPLACEMENT_STR="$2"
    FILENAME="$3"

    num_lines_matched=$(grep -c -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME")
    # Count number of matches, NOT lines (`grep -c` counts lines), 
    # in case there are multiple matches per line; see: 
    # https://superuser.com/questions/339522/counting-total-number-of-matches-with-grep-instead-of-just-how-many-lines-match/339523#339523
    num_matches=$(grep -o -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME" | wc -l)

    # If num_matches > 0
    if [ "$num_matches" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\n${num_matches} matches found on ${num_lines_matched} lines in file"\
                "\"${FILENAME}\":"
        # Now show these exact matches with their corresponding line 'n'umbers in the file
        grep -n --color=always -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME"
        # Now actually DO the string replacing on the files 'i'n place using the `sed` 
        # 's'tream 'ed'itor!
        sed -i "s|${REGEX_SEARCH}|${REPLACEMENT_STR}|g" "$FILENAME"
    fi
}
```

Place that in your ~/.bashrc file, for instance. Close and reopen your terminal and then use it.

### Example:

Replace `do` with `bo` so that "doing" becomes "boing" (I know, we should be fixing spelling errors not creating them :) ):

```
$ gs_replace_str "do" "bo" test_folder/test2.txt 

9 matches found on 6 lines in file "test_folder/test2.txt":
1:hey how are you doing today
2:hey how are you doing today
3:hey how are you doing today
4:hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today
5:hey how are you doing today
6:hey how are you doing today?
$SHLVL:3
```

Screenshot of the output, to show the matched text being highlighted in red:

[image]

### References:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/339522/counting-total-number-of-matches-with-grep-instead-of-just-how-many-lines-match/339523#339523
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144158/how-to-check-if-sed-has-changed-a-file/61238414#61238414

Comment: I tried to use your `find_and_replace.sh` to find `@Table(name = "` and replace it with `@Table(name = "V_` but I failed in finding the right way of escaping parenthesis and double quotes.  Is it a bug due to the fact that it uses both `grep` and `sed`?

Comment: Hi @Pino, it would look like this: `find_and_replace.sh "path/to/some_file.txt" "" '@Table\(name = "' '@Table(name = "V_'`. Here we use single quotes (`'`) to surround the double quotes, and you have to escape parenthesis in regular expressions with a backslash (\\). See https://regex101.com/ to help you come up with regular expressions (regexs). If you copy and paste `@Table(name = "` into the regex box there, it will highlight the `(` in red, indicating it has a problem and needs to be escaped as `\(`.

Comment: Once you escape it, you can read the "EXPLANATION" section at the top-right of https://regex101.com/ for details.

Comment: @Pino, that being said, my Ripgrep (`rg`) wrapper called [`rg_replace`, or `rgr`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684926/114401) for short, is a **much better** tool! See [my other answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684926/114401). `rgr` is **waaaay** faster than both `grep` and `git grep`, and has a ton of features. It's my go-to tool. `rgr` gives you access to _all_ `rg` features while adding the `-R` option to do actual on-disk replacements.

Comment: So with 3 greps and 1 sed, each file will be read end to end 4 times. To change, say, a 2 GB log file, this function will process about 10 GB of data.

Answer (score 0):

My RipGrep Replace wrapper, [`rgr`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/rg_replace.sh), is now my go-to on-disk find-and-replace and `grep`-replacement tool, period. It is incredibly robust, fast, and thorough. Unlike `grep`, it handles a full feature-set of regular expression syntax. It is 0.348s/0.136s = **~3x faster** than `git grep`, and 0.806s/0.136s = **~6x faster** than GNU `grep` (see [RipGrep speed tests here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#quick-examples-comparing-tools)), *and* **`rgr` supports on-disk find-and-replace**!

My [`rgr` wrapper](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/rg_replace.sh) around the incredibly fast [RipGrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) (`rg`) tool gives it the ability to do on-disk textual replacements via a new `-R` option. I call my wrapper `rgr`, for "RipGrep Replace", since it will do the find-and-replace feature on your disk via the `-R` option I added.

See the installation instructions at the top of [`rg_replace.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/rg_replace.sh), so you can use it as `rgr`.

For additional information on it, see my comments [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-1004581477) and [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/74#issuecomment-1004583171).

Example usages as shown from the help menu, accessed via `rgr -h` or `rgr --help`, are here:

```
EXAMPLE USAGES:

    rgr foo -r boo
        Do a *dry run* to replace all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in this folder and down.
    rgr foo -R boo
        ACTUALLY REPLACE ON YOUR DISK all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in this folder and down.
    rgr foo -R boo file1.c file2.c file3.c
        Same as above, but only in these 3 files.
    rgr foo -R boo -g '*.txt'
        Use a glob filter to replace on your disk all instances of 'foo' with 'boo' in .txt files
        ONLY, inside this folder and down. Learn more about RipGrep's glob feature here:
        https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md#manual-filtering-globs
    rgr foo -R boo --stats
        Replace on your disk all instances of 'foo' with 'boo', showing detailed statistics.
```

See the `rgr --help` menu yourself for a full description.