# Using regular experision in "rpl" command

Tags: linux, regular-expression

I need to replace text in lots of files. I'm using `rpl` for this purpose, but I can't find any way to make it use regular expressions. Can `rpl` use "regex"? how?

**Edit:**
I'm using `rpl 1.5.2` from `Ubuntu 13.04` repositories.

Comment: Some of the approaches explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/22222) might work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the reference page for the original `rpl` it would seem to be able to support regex just fine.

- http://blake.ism.u-bordeaux1.fr/doc_link/C/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds4/rpl.htm

#### Example

> See the following for examples of replacing character strings.
>
> **Note:** If you are using a locale other than En_US, the following examples may not include all alphabetic characters.
>
> 1. To replace a legal FORTRAN identifier (an alphabetic character followed by as many as five alphanumeric characters) with xxx, enter:
>
>    ```
>    $ rpl '[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,5}' xxx
>    ```
> 2. To replace all occurrences of the character string sky with blue sky in the skyfile file and put the result in the bluefile file, enter:
>
>    ```
>    $ rpl sky "blue sky" <skyfile >bluefile
>    ```

However in testing the [Linux version of `rpl`](http://packages.qa.debian.org/r/rpl.html) it doesn't appear that regex was implemented in this version. None of my testing was able to make use of any regex features.

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work! I tried `rpl '[A-Za-z]' 'T' test.txt` and it found nothing while using `rpl 'A' 'T' test.txt` works!

Comment: @4r1y4n - that's what my testing is showing too. The original version from AIX did support this, but the linux ver. doesn't. As an alternative you could use `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.5.5 version on Linux does not support replacing regular expressions.

An alternative using SED is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282