# Replace copyrights recursively

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I have many files under the current directory.

Each file contains copyrights headers like,

```
    #
    # Copyright 2013 Company, Inc. All rights reserved. This software
    # is property of Company, Inc and contains trade secrets,
```

I want to replace `Copyright 2013 Company` by `Copyright 2014 Company`

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -r -i "/Copyright\/ 2014\/ Company/d" {} +
```

Comment: @Anthon find from xyz

Comment: Canonical QA: [How can I replace a string in a file(s)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`find . -type f -exec sed -r -i "s/Copyright 2013 Company/Copyright 2014 Company/g" {} \;`