# Works on command line but not in shell script

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have a file formated like below:

```
436541,000454056,Smith,john,jsmith,j-Smith@xxx.com
```

I want to extract out ",jsmith" and write it to another file "test.txt".

So I use:

```
grep -o '\,[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,7}' source.txt > test.txt
```

from the command line and it works fine.

when I use it from a shell script the test.txt file is empty

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -o '\,[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,7}' source.txt > test.txt
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why does `type grep` return? Do you have an alias `grep='grep -E'` or `grep=egrep`? `{1,7}` is extended RE syntax only recognised with `-E`.

Comment: type grep
grep is aliased to `/bin/grep -E'

Comment: Aliases are disabled in scripts, so just fill in the complete command you see in `set -x` mode into the script.

Comment: And don't do `alias grep='grep -E'`, that's silly.

Comment: Why `grep` but `cut -d, -f5`?

Answer (score 2):

By default, `grep` uses [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) (BRE) which don't support `{N}`. If it works on the commandline, you most probably have `grep` aliased to `grep -E` or `grep -P`. You can check by running

```
alias | grep grep
```

Aliases are not enabled in scripts. As explained in `man bash`:

```
Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless  the
expand_aliases  shell option is set using shopt.
```

So, in a non-interactive shell, which is what you get when you run a script, aliases won't work. You have two options, either enable the aliases explicitly in your script and then source your `~/.bashrc` file to get the alias definitions (there's no need to escape the `,`, by the way):

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
grep -o ',[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,7}' source.txt > test.txt
```

Or, far simpler, use `grep -E` in the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -Eo ',[a-z][a-z0-9]{1,7}' source.txt > test.txt
```

You might also want to consider [tools like `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210337/22222) that are designed to work on field-delimited data though. Chances are they will make your life much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file has the same structure you could also use awk

```
awk -F"," '{print $5}' INPUTFILE.txt >> test.txt
```

There is also `cut` as Costas mentioned in the comments

```
cut -d"," -f5 INPUTFILE.txt >> test.txt
```