# how can i extract the second and third word of a line{that starts with 9} from a file where words are seperate with |?

Tags: awk, grep

```
 case "$3" in 
     -id)
         echo "Lines matches with the pattern $4 :" 
                #grep -oP $4 $2

                ;;
 esac
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to U&L SE. Please [edit] your question to provide an example of your input and the corresponding matched output.

Comment: Relevant: [How can I extract/change lines in a text file whose data are separated into fields?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210336).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below awk command :

```
awk -F"|" '$2 ~ /^9/ && $3 ~ /^9/ { print $2,$3 }' filename
```

Output contain space between second and third word but you can set it according to your need with OFS.

Edit :

your program will look like this :

```
case "$3" in 
     -id)
         echo "Lines matches with the pattern $4 :" 
         filename=$2
         id=$4
         echo "`grep "^$id" $filename | awk -F"|" -v ID="$id" '$1==ID'|awk -F "|" '{print $2,$3,$5}'`"
                 ;;
 esac
```

Comment: -F is a field seperator and assign $1,$2 ... based on it.
($2 ~ /^9/ && $3 ~ /^9/ ): Compares second and third word with a regular expression that starts with 9. If both the conditions met it will print those words using { print $2,$3 } .

Comment: `awk -F"|" '/^9/{ print $2,$3 }' filename` should suffice, no? The requirement was for the entire line to start with `9`

Comment: I answered considering second and third words to be started with 9. If line should start with 9 then awk -F"|" '/^9/{ print $2,$3 }' filename should suffice.

Comment: can you please provide me with the sample entries of your file like one or two sample lines so that i can understand what your requirement exactly is ?

Comment: edited the answer. Let me know if that works for you and if you require any other check as well.

Comment: made one edit, Hope it should work. Sorry for non-ending edits :( .

Comment: @Vinnet Sharma it actually didn' t work at all :(  ,it only prints the message of the first echo and then an empty line

Comment: not sure. I have created a similar file here in my system and tried the command and it is working. could you please share your output ?

Comment: did the last edit work at the file?my programm didn t find the lines with id 993,could you please expalin your last edit because it seems ok but it didnt work on my file

Comment: Yes,it is working fine.Earlier it was displaying results for all the id's containing 993 at start i.e. 993,9934 and so on.Now it is only displaying results where id matches exactly 993 or whatever the input has been provided.
Actually shell variable doesn't work in awk so i have reassigned the shell's variable value to awk's variable (-v switch for variable in awk) and used it to compare with first word. If condition meets, it will process the next awk.

Comment: try removing echo part :
grep "^$id" $filename | awk -F"|" -v ID="$id" '$1==ID'|awk -F "|" '{print $2,$3,$5}'
For me it is working both ways with echo and without echo. Not sure where the gap is.

Comment: @Vinnet Sharma  without echo i have no results ,although with echo i had an empty line as a result (by the way thanks for the help)

Comment: can you mail me the file and script ( if not confidential ) at vin100.sharma@gmail.com .