# delete lines in csv based on character count in a specific column

Tags: text-processing, columns, special-characters

I have a large csv / text file with only two columns.
I want to delete lines with 12 or fewer characters in column #2
the columns are separated with a ";"

data in file looks like:

```
skhfkshfkhaslkfhsk;2164641854641

wfhixuhvlwrhiuag;654611968
```

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210336/how-can-i-extract-change-lines-in-a-text-file-whose-data-are-separated-into-fiel

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
awk -F ";" 'length($2)>12' file.csv
```