# Shell: How to get number from file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
1  2  5  7
```

I have numbers like this in a text file. How can I print the third number using a shell script?

Answer (score 4):

The shell isn't a good tool for this sort of thing. [There are tools designed especially for this type of task](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210336/22222):

```
$ awk '{print $3}' file
5
```

Or, if this is a tab-separated file:

```
$ cut -f3 file
5
```

If not, you can convert the consecutive spaces to tabs and still use `cut`:

```
$ sed 's/  */\t/g' file | cut -f3
5
```

Or, convert them to single spaces and use `cut -d' '`:

```
$ sed 's/  */ /g' file | cut -d' ' -f3
5
```

If you insist on doing it in the shell, you can do something like:

```
$ while read a b c rest; do echo "$c"; done < file
5
```

Or

```
$ nums=( $(cat file) )
$ echo "${nums[2]}"
5
```

Comment: Nice solutions - apart for the "while read" loop. Albeit technically correct, one should avoid solutions in which elements which can be parametrised are actually hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to display the third item in all lines of a file (assuming the text file is named *numbers.txt*):

```
while read one two three four; do 
  echo "$three"; 
done < numbers.txt
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for the third item in all lines, just the third item. Besides, this solution is not prone to parametrisation, so should the OP change their mind and decided that they needed a fourth number, or nth given number, there's no easy way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the third line of a text file, something like:

```
cat yourfile | head -n 3 | tail -n 1
```

should do the job. If you have all the values in one line, you may want to reorder  them first

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  | sed -e "s# #\n#g"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

There are many other solutions possible, this is just something which came to my mind first.

Comment: You don't need cat (in fact, that's a classic UUoC) you can just run `head - n 3 yourfile |...`. Also, note that `\n` for a newline is a GNU `sed`0extension and isn't supported by most other sed implementations.

Comment: I know, but I decided that it would be more clear this way as every program has only one specific task to do so for an educational purposes it may be better. 

Also, it's far from optimal anyway, as it requires running 2 or 3 programs to do the job, while you can achieve the same result using only the shell mechanisms, running only one additional program at the most. Yet, it still is a viable solution, and there's always more than one way to do the job. :-)