# find and replace strings with another string command line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a Ad-blocking hosts file with `0.0.0.0` IPs pointing to URLs. How to replace `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.1` command line without any visual text editor ? Manually doing this with `nano` , `vi` etc. is impossible , the list have above 15k lines.

**from this**

```
0.0.0.0  c.one97adworks.com
0.0.0.0  0koryu0.easter.ne.jp
0.0.0.0  static.super-links.net
```

**to this**

```
127.0.0.1  c.one97adworks.com
127.0.0.1  0koryu0.easter.ne.jp
127.0.0.1  static.super-links.net
```

at once.

My shell bash 4.3.33.

**UPDATE**
**two down votes ? please leave comments.**

Comment: See this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/vi-vim-editor-search-and-replace-examples/

Comment: The question was probably downvoted, as it could have been solved by a minimal search effort (e.g. "text replacement linux"). Here a general answers to your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Comment: The downvote button is tagged as, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the contents in file1.txt, the results will be in file2.txt with the following:

```
sed 's/^0\.0\.0\.0/127.0.0.1/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: This would replace `0a0b0c0` etc.

Comment: You need to escape the dots: `sed 's/0\.0\.0\.0/127.0.0.1/' ...`.

Comment: Problem solved,  what a stupid question!!  `'s/0\.0\.0\.0/127.0.0.1/'` . Backslashes before dots are must.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lpe 's/^(0\.){3}0/127.0.0.1/' file > newfile
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since the file is structured in this way you **can** also do this in Vi, nano or any other text editor; simply use its find/replace command.

E.g. in nano, the simplest text editor around:

1. open the file
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
3. enter `0.0.0.0` as search string
4. enter `127.0.0.1` as replacement string
5. <kbd>A</kbd> to replace all matches
6. save the edited file

Comment: ...and in `vi`, `%s/^0\.0\.0\.0/127.0.0.1/` _Enter_ followed by `ZZ` and _Enter_ could also work.