# Escape >');} < / in sed

Tags: sed, replace, special-characters

In 30 files in 30 directories, I want to find:

```
script>');} < /script>
```

and replace it with:

```
script>');} < /script-->
```

- What special characters do I need to escape in the find field?
- Do I need to escape the same characters in the *replace_with* field?
- Is backslash the appropriate escape key?

I will use the following method:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/"find"/"replace_with"/g' {} +
```

That method has worked for simple replacements.

I read [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files), and other pages, but could not find the answer I need.

Comment: `sed "s^script>');} < /script^&--^g"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sed -i "s+< /script>+< /script-->+g"`. So final command would become

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s+< /script>+< /script-->+g" {} +
```