# Replace only in particular range string

Tags: sed, replace

In the canonical [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files) in *3. Replace only if the string is found in a certain context*,  I'm trying to implement the replace of a pipe with white spaces in file with structure like this:

```
12/12/2000|23:16:03|Shell Sc|8332|START|TEXT|WITH|SPACES|-|[END]|[Something else]
```

I need it like this:

```
12/12/2000|23:16:03|Shell Sc|8332|START TEXT WITH SPACES -|[END]|[Something else]
```

The code:

```
echo "12/12/2000|23:16:03|Shell Sc|8332|START|TEXT|WITH|SPACES|-|[END]|[Something else]" | \
 sed 's/\(START.*\)\|/ \1/g'
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your command is that even with the `g` flag set, a particular portion of the text to be matched can only be included in a *single* match.  Since `.*` is greedy, you will only end up removing the final pipe character.  Not to mention your space in the replacement text is in the wrong place.

You could do this with a repeated `s` command in a loop, running until it doesn't match anything.  Like so:

```
sed -e ':looplabel' -e 's/\(START.*\)|\(.*|\[END\)/\1 \2/;t looplabel'
```

Or, using a shorter loop label:

```
sed -e ':t' -e 's/\(START.*\)|\(.*|\[END\)/\1 \2/;tt'
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, all the `|` you want replaced with spaces come immediately after a capital letter and immediately before a capital letter or a `-`. You can therefore use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ perl -ple 's/(?<=[A-Z])\|(?=[A-Z-])/ /g' file
12/12/2000|23:16:03|Shell Sc|8332|START TEXT WITH SPACES -|[END]|[Something else]
```