# How to change certain word in certain line in a file

Tags: sed

i have a file in which i have to change a word and then save it by same name.

for ex- 
for file "name"-

```
my name is joe (original data)
my name is roy (changed data)
```

how to do it in best possible way?

Comment: rather than posting text, post input file with filename and desired output

Comment: @don_crissti : yeah, but its pretty unclear

Comment: you can find the answer in here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Answer (score 1):

To change all occurrences of `joe` in a file to `roy`:

```
sed 's/joe/roy/g' /path/to/the/file > /path/to/new/file
```

To change all occurrence of `joe` in a file to `roy` on lines containing `my name`:

```
sed '/my name/s/joe/roy/g' /path/to/the/file > /path/to/new/file
```

Comment: but this changes the data in file.. i want to add changes to a new file.. but using '>' doesnot work for me.. plz help..

Comment: I shall edit my answer to reflect that you want the changes to go into a new file.