# How to search-replace-backup files recursively in linux?

Tags: backup, file-search

I'd like to recursively search for a string within all files in a folder.

If the string was found, backup the file to the same location (copy to `<filename>-orig`) and replace the found string with another string.

**How to do it?**

Can I do it with a single command? Thanks.

Comment: something like `sed -i.orig 's/abc/xyz/' <list of files>` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files for detailed discussion on replacing strings

Comment: and `<list of files>` can be something like `$(grep -l abc *.txt)` to get list of files ending with .txt containing the string abc

Comment: I meant all files in a folder. Changing the description...

Comment: does any of these answers helped you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two `-exec` operation of `find`, firstly to find all files containing matching string and secondly to replace the string with replace keyword (keeping backup of original file), like

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il "searchstring" {} \; -exec sed -i.bak \
's/searchstring/replacestring/' {} \;
```

**Explanation :**

- `-exec grep -il "searchstring"` : search for "searchsring"
- `-exec sed -i.bak 's/searchstring/replacestring/'` : If any files found containing string then keep backup of file their and replace with "replacestring".

Note that in this case the second command will only run if the first one returns successfully.