# Replace a value in a file, in a certain context, with an operation result

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I have an array of JSON object with inside local urls and speed parameters like `[{server:"192.168.0.100", speed:34}, {server:"192.168.0.130", speed:52},...]`
I need to update the speed value for each server..

Reading links like
  *[Replace only if the string is found in a certain context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024/198416)*  
I've tried this:

```
#first by first I delete the old value
sed -i 's/speed:\(.\), //g' $FILENAME
sed -i 's/speed:\(..\), //g' $FILENAME
sed -i 's/speed:\(...\), //g' $FILENAME
sed -i 's/speed:\(....\), //g' $FILENAME

#then I've tried to calculate the new one
sed -i "s/server:\"\(192.168.0...\)\"/server:\"\1\", speed:$( ping -c3 \\1 | grep rtt | cut -f 5 -d '/' ), /g" $FILENAME
```

But it doesn't work:

> unknown host \1

Comment: not sure if one can pass captured group in `sed` to external command...

Comment: The shown data format isn't valid json. Maybe you should elaborate why you have chosen this format and not csv or whatsoever...

Comment: why is not valid?? Anyway I don't mind the format or the use of sed but I need it in a text file. So If you have an other idea to replace/update that value please help me

Comment: @lunix15 Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: ah ok.. but it doesn't matter in javascript when you read json. Anyway thanks

Comment: Please show us your expected *input* and desired *output*.  The approach you are using is extraordinarily complicated for something so simple; I can't even tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: think about a simple GUI showing the last speed for each server and so a script that updates those speeds every x seconds.. so the starting value is like [{server:"192.168.0.100", speed:34}, {server:"192.168.0.130", speed:52}] that have to be update.. so it could become for example like [{server:"192.168.0.100", speed:21}, {server:"192.168.0.130", speed:94}] evaluate by ping test

Comment: The JSON that you're sowing is unfortunately not valid. The keys should be quoted.

Comment: no need to quote keys in javascript

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, I've found a solution using a mix of arrays and sed..:

```
#delete the old values
sed -i 's/speed:\(.\), //g' "$FILENAME"
sed -i 's/speed:\(..\), //g' "$FILENAME"
sed -i 's/speed:\(...\), //g' "$FILENAME"
sed -i 's/speed:\(....\), //g' "$FILENAME"

#create an array with just the urls
SERVER=( $(sed -nre 's/.*server:"(.*)".*/\1/p' "$FILENAME") )

#for each element
for element in $(seq 0 $((${#SERVER[@]}-1)))
do
    #calculate the new average ping speed
    SPEED[element]="$( sudo ping -c2 "${SERVER[element]}" | grep rtt | cut -f 5 -d '/' )"

    #if server is not available
    if [ -z "${SPEED[element]}" ]; then SPEED[element]=1000 ; fi

    #add the old server speed
    sed -i "s/\"\(${SERVER[element]}\)\"/\"\1\", speed:${SPEED[element]}/g" "$FILENAME"
done
```

Maybe is not performing but it works and could be usefull

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) and also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: I sed it is not performing and of course is a bad practice, but for one shot execution it worked

Comment: that’s fine for one shot, but not so useful for people trying to learn by reading answers on this site.

Comment: I'm sorry you think so.. when I found that solution I thought it would be useful while someone (or me) find a better way.. If you think this solution is too bad I can remove it

Comment: I don't think removal is called for, nor even editing really.  (The post is pretty old and not likely to be broadly seen.)  Just, next time you post a question about text processing, I suggest you include an example input and example desired output.  That way people don't have to reverse-engineer the code in your question in order to answer.