# Double quote value assignments stored in a CSV?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, csv-simple

I have a file that contains text as follows:

```
dt=2016-06-30,path=path1,site=US,mobile=1
dt=2016-06-21,path=path2,site=UK,mobile=0
```

I want to convert it to text with double-quoted values in the key-value pairs, like so:

```
dt="2016-06-30",path="path1",site="US",mobile="1"
dt="2016-06-21",path="path2",site="UK",mobile="0"
```

How can I place every value within double quotes, using Sed or any other command?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/135943

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using [Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

```
sed -e 's/=\([^,]*\)/="\1"/g' file.txt
```

### Using [Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (f=1;f<=NF;f++) {sub(/=/,"&\"",$f); sub(/$/,"\"",$f)}; print}' file.txt
```

Or, shorter:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (f=1;f<=NF;f++) {gsub(/=|$/,"&\"",$f)} print}' file.txt
```

Shorter still:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (f=1;f<=NF;f++) {gsub(/=|$/,"&\"",$f)}} 1' file.txt
```

### Using [ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)

Ex is designed for file *editing*, but you can preview changes without actually saving them back to the file like so:

```
ex -sc '%s/=\([^,]*\)/="\1"/g | %p | q!' file.txt
```

To actually make the changes and save them to the file, use:

```
ex -sc '%s/=\([^,]*\)/="\1"/g | x' file.txt
```

However if you give a pattern which is found nowhere in the file (e.g. there is no `=` anywhere in the file) then Ex will not exit automatically.  Thus for better robustness I usually use `printf` to pass commands to Ex:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/=\([^,]*\)/="\1"/g' %p | ex file.txt
```

And to save changes:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/=\([^,]*\)/="\1"/g' x | ex file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`

```
$ # unlike sed/awk, newline is still part of input record
$ perl -pe 's/=\K[^,\n]*/"$&"/g' ip.txt 
dt="2016-06-30",path="path1",site="US",mobile="1"
dt="2016-06-21",path="path2",site="UK",mobile="0"

$ # or chomp newline and add it back while printing
$ perl -lpe 's/=\K[^,]+/"$&"/g' ip.txt
dt="2016-06-30",path="path1",site="US",mobile="1"
dt="2016-06-21",path="path2",site="UK",mobile="0"
```

Comment: You don't need to have a newline in the bracket expression. the characters from the last = to end of line are already non-comma characters.

Comment: @glennjackman it is treating newline as non-comma character for me.. `perl v5.22.1`.. with `-l` option it won't be needed as you put it

Answer (score 3):

### Using awk

```
awk '{gsub(/=/, "=\""); gsub(/,/,"\","); print $0"\""}' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0):

```
$ mlr put 'for (k,v in $*) {$[k] = "\"".v."\""}' mobile.dat
dt="2016-06-30",path="path1",site="US",mobile="1"
dt="2016-06-21",path="path2",site="UK",mobile="0"
```