# What does **/*(D.) mean in (zsh) sed arguments?

Tags: sed, zsh, string

I see this command being given as how to search and replace strings in files in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/112024):

```
sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **/*(D.)
```

What does the pattern `*/*(D)` mean? I am not sure what they are called, so cannot google them. Is this part of sed parameters, or is it part of zsh? Thanks!

Comment: For the parenthesis part, with tab completion enabled you can type `echo *(` and then mash TAB to see a quick name/description table of the glob qualifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic name is *glob qualifiers*. For `zsh` there is a list under the [Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) section of the documentation.

```
Patterns used for filename generation may end in a list of qualifiers
enclosed in parentheses. The qualifiers specify which filenames that 
otherwise match the given pattern will be inserted in the argument list.
```

In particular:

```
.

    plain files
```

and

```
D

    sets the GLOB_DOTS option for the current pattern
```

Comment: Also, just for completeness sake, `**` matches directories recursively.