# Search and replace something contained in ' (single quotes)

Tags: linux, text-processing, files

In various files in lots of sub folders I have the following text in large text files, each unique

```
Linux.Secret = 'XYZZYXZYXZYXZYXZYXZ'
```

I would like to make it so all the `Linux.Secret = ''` are the same as `Linux.Secret = 'NEWSECRET'`

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to replace all lines which match the pattern `Linux.Secret = '[A-Z,a-z]'` with the string `Linux.Secret = 'NEWSECRET'` ?

Comment: Yes anything that starts with Linux.Secret = and enclosed in ''

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/112024#112024

Comment: Just need to adapt one of those answers for handling the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

First find all files that contains `Linux.Secret =` at the start of a line:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '^Linux.Secret =' {} ';'
```

Note that `grep -q` does not output anything, it just exits with a status depending on whether the expression could be matched or not.

Then, for all files that passes these tests (is a regular file and contains that text), we run a simple (GNU) `sed` command:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q '^Linux.Secret =' {} ';' \
    -exec sed -i "s/^Linux.Secret =.*/Linux.Secret = 'NewSecret'/" {} +
```

This makes the change in-place in the files by substituting the whole line with the line we'd like to have. We handle the single quotes by using double quotes around the expressions that require it.

If you need to be more careful with the matching and only match `Linux.Secrets =` followed by something in single quotes:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -E -q "^Linux.Secret = '[^']+'" {} ';' \
    -exec sed -E -i "s/^Linux.Secret = '[^']+'.*/Linux.Secret = 'NEWSECRET'/" {} +
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)