# How to use sed on all matching files?

Tags: sed, find, pipe

I am trying to run sed on the output from `find | grep \.ext$`
However, sed requires input file and output file.
How can I save the output line to a variable, or pass it to sed?

Comment: `sed` doesn't require an input file, just pipe the output to `sed`...

Comment: unless they want to have sed operate on the matching files (not on their file *names*)

Comment: Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/112024#112024

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice/321753#321753

Answer (score 6):

This is not true, `sed` does not **require** an input file.

> Sed is a stream editor [...] used to perform basic text transformations on an input stream (a file **or input from a pipeline**). ([via](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed))

But in your case you want to manipulate files, and not streams, so yes, you need it.

---

You don't need `grep` here, you can use `find -name "*.ext"`.
If you then want to run `sed` on all files that have been found, use `find -exec` to execute a command on any file that has been found.

```
find -name "*.ext" -exec sed -i '...' {} \;
```

---

If for any reason you want to use filenames coming from `grep` (e.g. your input is not from `find`), you can use `xargs`:

```
grep \.ext$ list_of_files | xargs -I{} sed -i '...' {}
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: `touch "file name.ext"` for a failure case

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` with multiple input files:

```
sed 'what/you/wanna/do' file1 file2 file3
sed 'what/you/wanna/do' file*
sed 'what/you/wanna/do' *.txt
sed 'what/you/wanna/do' $(find | grep \.ext)
```

To save the changes, instead of printing them on stdout, use the option `-i` (inplace):

```
sed -i 'what/you/wanna/do' $(find | grep \.ext)
```

Comment: How does this integrate with their `find`?

Comment: `touch "file name.txt"` for a failure case