# How to use SED or AWK to replace single static string in file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a Bash script doing something. It contains a single static statement `CHANGE_ME`. What I want is to replace `CHANGE_ME` with the output from variable i.e.:
If $VAR is set to 192.168.x.x then replace `CHANGE_ME` with `some-text`
How can I do this?

The script has variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
NODE_NAME="CHANGE_ME"
...
```

In another start-up script I want to replace `CHANGE_ME` depends of the returned VAR value:

```
if [[ "$SOMETHING" == "true" ]]; then
    NETWORK=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
```

and if NETWORK returns for instance 192.168.x.y then replace CHANGE_ME with X else if NETWORK returns 172.16 then replace CHANGE_ME with Y

Comment: Add sample text and the expected output to your question and specify what `some-text` is.

Comment: @NasirRiley added more details

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files)

Comment: In which file exactly do you want to replace the `CHANGE_ME`? In the "bash script that does something"?