# How to use sed to replace a string in double quotes with a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a file that includes this line:

```
  master_green_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
```

My bash script will have a parameter like `userdata_version=v2.21`.

How can I use `sed` to replace anything between the `""` (i.e. `"v1.16/"`) with `$userdata_version`?

I cannot hard code `v1.16` as it keeps on changing.

Comment: Edit question to tell us: What have you tried?, what problem did you get?

Comment: Could be a shell quoting problem. Did you put the arguments to `sed` in single quotes?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

To use `sed`, for the scenario that you describe, with an input file like this:

```
master_green_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
master_blue_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
```

This script<sup>*</sup>

```
#!/bin/sh
  
userdata_version=v2.21
sed -i -e "/master_green_cloud_init_version/s/\".*\"/\"${userdata_version}\"/" input.txt
```

results in

```
$ more input.txt
master_green_cloud_init_version = "v2.21"
master_blue_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
$
```

Note that you need double quotes for the `sed` expression, in order to use the shell variable, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006933/4424636) to [Shell variables in sed script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006910/4424636).

Then you also need to escape the double quotes that you are searching for, using `\"`. You will need to do this twice, once for the starting double quote and once for the end.

The `-i` works on the input file rather than just outputting the result to `stdout`.

---

**Note**: If, for some reason, you want to keep the forward slash at the end of the version string, then use an escaped forward slash (`\/`), like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

userdata_version=v2.21
sed  -e "/master_green_cloud_init_version/s/\".*\/\"/\"${userdata_version}\/\"/" input.txt
```

which, for the same input file, gives

```
master_green_cloud_init_version = "v2.21/"
master_blue_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
```

---

<sup>*</sup> From [How to use sed to find and replace text in files in Linux / Unix shell](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/):

> #### How to use sed to match word and perform find and replace
>
> In this example only find word ‘love’ and replace it with ‘sick’ if
> line content a specific string such as FOO:
>
> ```
> sed -i -e '/FOO/s/love/sick/' input.txt
> ```

See also [How can I replace a string in a file(s)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/97255)

Comment: sorry, as the replace string is a folder, still needs a backslash, userdata_version=v2.21/,  then your solution does not work with backslack in the string to be replaced. please help?

Comment: thanks, it works in sh or some bash as well, but in my environment (jenkins pipeline kubernetes pod, it does not work).  it is replace as the value of $userdata_version, and "master_green_cloud_init_version =" was removed.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify that in your question, you said "My bash script will have..." and you tagged the question with the bash tag. I think that is a different question altogether, like "Why doesn't sed work as expected in 'jenkins pipeline kubernetes pod'?"

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58734288/4424636) to [Jenkins: Pipeline sh bad substitution error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37219348/4424636) will help you. If it does, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  that the file is a configuration file written in [TOML format](https://toml.io/en/), then you may use [the `tomlq` parser](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to change the value, given the shell variable `userdata_version` with a new value:

```bsh
tomlq -t --arg newversion "$userdata_version" \
        '.master_green_cloud_init_version |= $newversion' file.toml
```

This would update the value of the top-level key `master_green_cloud_init_version` to the value assigned with `--arg` to the internal variable `$newversion`.  The modified document is written to standard output (you may do in-place editing with the `--in-place` option).

Testing:

```
$ cat file.toml
  master_green_cloud_init_version = "v1.16/"
```

```
$ userdata_version=v2.21
$ tomlq -t --arg newversion "$userdata_version" '.master_green_cloud_init_version |= $newversion' file.toml
master_green_cloud_init_version = "v2.21"
```