# Bulk Rename of Folders with Numbers

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I need to bulk rename files called plt????? to plt??????.

They're in numerical order from 0 to 99500 every 500, however I have some over 100,000 so I'd like them all to be in 6 figures.

Aim: current - plt99500 goal - plt099500

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi. There's literally hundreds of questions on *similar* problems on here, so chances are you can piece together an answer by yourself! Could you explain what you've tried so far? What existing answers on this site have you looked into and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume that all your files are in the same directory, that none of the files can have the same name (e.g. you don't have `plt500` and already have `plt000500`), *all* names consist of nothing but `plt` and then the number, and all files starting with `plt` need to be renamed, then you can do this:

```bash
for f in plt*; do
   numNoZero=$(sed 's/^0*//' <<<"${f/plt/}")
   echo mv -- "$f" "$(printf 'plt%06d' "$numNoZero")";
done
```

First, we iterate over all files and directories (letus know if you need to skip directories) whose name starts with `plt`, saving each as `$f`. Next, `${f/plt/}` is the file name with the `plt` removed, so it should be just the number. We feed this through a `sed` command that removes any leading 0s, in case you have any, and save the result (the number without leading 0s) as `$numNoZero`. Next, we use `printf`, telling it t print `plt` and then the number, padded to 6 digits (`%06d`) and use this as the name we want to `mv` to.

If this looks right, remove the `echo` and re-run to actually rename the files.

Alternatively, if you have Perl `rename` (known as `rename` on Ubuntu and other Debian systems, `perl-rename` or `prename` in others), you can just do:

```
rename -n 's/plt0*(\d+?)$/sprintf("plt%06d", "$1")/e' plt*
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'd not come across the ${f/plt}, sed or %06d commands before but this worked great!

Comment: @GillyRussell you're welcome. See [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for a reference on shell string manipulation tools, and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/22222) for a more general resource for string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%06d", $&/e' ./plt[0-9]*
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.